# How can I make a scoreboard card xcode

Tags: ios, uitableview

The thing is that I'm making a golf-app and I need the users to fill out all their scores in it. Well I really want the view to look like a golf-scoreboard but how can I achieve this :o?

[image: This is what a scoreboard looks like]

Thanks guys, much appriciated :D!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you just looking for a basic design direction?

Comment: Are you asking us to write your app for you? Or is there some specific issue you're having trouble with?

Comment: personally I'm a big fan of using HTML 5 and a UIWebView for stuff like this.  It's a lot easier to design in Safari and then move into an app later.

Comment: I am simple looking for a tip of what kind of element to use for this kind of project. A webview would work but isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a tableview and use this control: https://github.com/allaboutapps/A3GridTableView

You need to change this according to your needs.. Hope this helps you to start..